# Why is the Matches function of Regex so fast?

Tags: c#, regex

My English skill is poor because I'm not native English speaker.
I hope you to understand.

I have used the Regex function in .Net.
Someday, I tried the test that call the Matches function of the Regex with 117000 string and 46 patterns.
As a result, was generated 51870 tokens faster than 2ms.

Here the amazing thing was it took only 2ms.
Converting the generated collection to the List took 250ms. (The code is like the below.)

```
var list = collection.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();
```

I couldn't believe this so I tried several times and the result same.

I curious why Matches function of Regex so fast.
Does it use the Async or Parallel mechanism internally?

In the test, I called the function like the following.

```
var collection = Regex.Matches(targetString(117000), this.rule(46), RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

Thank you for reading.

---

The full source code is below.
please input many strings in the test.txt.
I deleted "\r", "\n", "\t" pattern to make it simple.
As a result, the numbers of the generated token was 45450.
Thank you for your attention.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string targetString = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

        string pattern = "(\\breturn\\b)|(\\bwhile\\b)|(\\bconst\\b)|(\\belse\\b)|(\\bvoid\\b)|(\\bint\\b)|(\\bif\\b)|" +
    "([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*)|([0-9]+)|" +
    "(//.*$)|(\\!\\=)|(\\%\\=)|(\\>\\=)|(\\/\\=)|(\\+\\=)|(\\|\\|)|(\\-\\-)|(\\+\\+)|(\\*\\=)|(\\-\\=)|(\\<\\=)|(\\=\\=)|(\\&\\&)|(\\*\\/)|(\\/\\*)|(\\*)|(\\!)|(\\+)|(\\%)|(\\))|(\\;)|(\\()|(\\/)|" +
    "(\\{)| (\\})| (\\-)| (\\])| (\\[)|(\\,)|(\\>)|(\\ )|(\\=)|(\\<)";


        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        var collection = Regex.Matches(targetString, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", sw.Elapsed);

        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        var list = collection.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", sw.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

My results show like below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should read https://www.loggly.com/blog/regexes-the-bad-better-best/

Comment: Regex implementation and performance is a big topic. But for most regex patterns the time to match would be O(stringlength). And 117k is not that big for a modern PC.

Comment: Please provide the full source code. I have the suspicion that you use linq to get the list of matches. With linq, concrete predicates will not be executed immediately, but only once the result is actually accessed. So you don't measure the actual execution time of the pattern matching.

Comment: Ok, wait, please...

Comment: We still can't see the results of the ToList(). And always run benchmarks in Release mode w/o the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RegExpMatches` method returns a `MatchCollection` object which contains the matches. However, this object by default operates in a *lazy* mode, which means that it will not go through the whole string and find all matches at once but always only as far as necessary to find the next match.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection):

> The MatchCollection object is populated as needed on a match-by-match
>   basis. It is equivalent to the regular expression engine calling the
>   Regex.Match method repeatedly and adding each match to the collection.
>   This technique is used when the collection is accessed through its
>   GetEnumerator method, or when it is accessed using the foreach
>   statement (in C#) or the For Each...Next statement (in Visual Basic).

So, in you code, the actual search is not done on the call to `Matches()` but only when you try to turn the `MatchCollection` into a `List`.

---

To measure the full time for the pattern searching, you could force direct evaluation by accessing the `Count` property from the code.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

var collection = Regex.Matches(targetString, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

int count = collection.Count; // Force immediate full evaluation

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Found {0}, Elapsed={1}", count, sw.Elapsed);
```

Comment: Ah... it was a lazy mode... Thank you for your answer.
But even though a lazy mode, why can compiler show whole collection data?
is It (the thing compiler show whole data)  irrelevant with lazy mode?

Comment: As soon as you look at the data in the debugger, the evaluation does then happen because the compiler accesses the Count property (and then turns the lazy collection into a list just as you do in your later code).

Comment: Ah... I understand. 
Thanks to you, I learned a lot.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexMatchCollection.cs,a6c6a833160c7736) to see how the lazy evaluation is implemented.